# Summation involving Golden ratio

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, summation

Find the value of $$S=\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{m^2n}{\phi^m\left(n\phi^m+m\phi^n\right)}$$

I have written it as

$$S=\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\frac{m}{\phi^m}}{\frac{\phi^m}{m}+\frac{\phi^n}{n}}$$

Let $f_k=\frac{\phi^k}{k}$  Then

$$S=\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{f_m\left(f_m+f_n\right)} $$

so we get

$$S=\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{f_m}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\left(f_m+f_n\right)} $$

Can we proceed from here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Exploit symmetry:
$$ \sum_{m,n\geq 1}\frac{1}{f_n(f_n+f_m)}=\sum_{m,n\geq 1}\frac{1}{f_m(f_n+f_m)}=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{m,n\geq 1}\frac{\frac{1}{f_n}+\frac{1}{f_m}}{f_n+f_m}=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{m,n\geq 1}\frac{1}{f_m f_n}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{f_n}\right)^2$$
and
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{f_n}=\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{k}{\phi^k}=\frac{1/\phi}{(1-1/\phi)^2}=2+\sqrt{5}.$$